# Manipulating the CSS of a specific <div> that does not have a class or id

Tags: jquery, css, class, html

I am just learning jQuery and is a bit confused about this:

Let's say I need to provide a jQuery script that will add a class name of 'ourClass' to a `<div>`. I would use the following code:

```
$("div").addClass('ourClass');
```

Is the above correct? After I add a classname to this specific `<div>` would there be conflicts later if I want to add another classname to another specific `<div>`?

Basic question help appreciated.

Comment: no there will be no issue what i think

Comment: it will add class to all the `div`s

Comment: OK thanks. So that code would select all the `div`s? It really depends on what's in this `div`? For example: `$("div[style*="height: 34px"]")` would select a more specific `div`?

Comment: yes this would be perfectly fine but this would add class to each div available at the moment in the current page.

Comment: By the way another one: In a selector is it both fine using ' and "? For example: `$('div[style*="height: 34px"]')` and `$("div[style*="height: 34px"]")` would both be fine?

Comment: No! there would be a syntax error if you see. but better to use `.filter()` method for it.

Comment: @JohnS Yes (Maybe you need 'escape' the latter one) but I would strongly advise *not* to select by specific attributes such as those. These are what classes are exactly for.

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery selector `$("div")` will select ALL `div` elements on the page. Probably not what you want.

Instead, look at the parent elements and try to figure out a selector that will target the element in question.

For example...

```
<header>
  <div>abc</div>
  <div>def</div>
  <div>ghi</div>
</header>
<main>
  <div>jkl</div>
  <div>mno</div>
  <div>pqr</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>stu</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

**Selectors:**

- The selector `$("header div")` will select the first three divs. If you need to select only one of these, you can use `$("header div").first()`, `$("header div").last()`, or `$("header div").eq(1)`. (`eq()` will select by index, where the index of the first element is `0`).
- `$("main div")` will select the last four (any `div` element that is a child of `main`, including "stu"). This is also equivalent to `$("main").find("div")`.
- `$("main > div")` will select any `div` that is a direct child of `main` ("jkl", "mno", and "pqr", but not "stu"). This is also equivalent to `$("main").children("div")`.
- `$("main li div")` will select "stu".

Usually it's best to simply give your elements a class name or id if you need to target them with JQuery, but it's always possible to get creative with your selectors if you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Any elements can have any number of classes. But same id should not be there in a document.

Answer (score 0):

use `.filter()` as per your comments:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('height') === '34px'
}).addClass('ourClass');
```

---

The above code snippet adds the `ourClass` css class to a div which has the height of `34px`.

Answer (score 0):

As King King points out, the above would find every div on the page and add the class ourClass to it.  The selector portion of jQuery works just like CSS, so if you had a rule in your CSS that was div {background-color: blue;], it would apply a blue background to every div on the page.  By providing more specificity in your selector, you can narrow, or target, specific elements on the page.

And, just like your standard mark up can have multiple classes for a single element, you can add multiple class with jQuery.